# Cancellation properties of matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

- $AB=AC$ implies $B=C$
- $BA=CA$ implies $B=C$

These statements are true if $A$ is invertible. That is proved easily by multiplication of the inverse on both sides.

However, shouldn't it be the case that the two statements hold whenever $A$ is one to one, that is, its null space is $\{0\}$ which will be satisfied by non singular square matrices as well as nonsquare matrices which have a greater dimension in the output space, whose columns are linearly independent.

If not please provide counter examples and if yes, provide a logical explanation or, much less preferably, a rigorous proof.

Comment: The result follows immediately from injectivity: If $A$ is injective then $A(B-C) x = 0$ implies $(B-C)x = 0$. Hence $B=C$.

Comment: The second statement holds if $A$ is *surjective*.

Comment: ok that is perfect for case 1. I am convinced,For the second statement, I am now completely confused and forgot my own logic for why i suspected it would be injective... Why do you claim it needs to necessarily be surjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter example to point $2$ where $A$ is injective:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix} = 1$

and

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix} = 1$

where $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}$ has LI columns and so is injective.

A straightforward way to understand your question is to note the following:

$A$ LI columns $\iff$ $A$ injective $\iff$ A has a left inverse

and

$A$ LI rows $\iff$ $A$ surjective $\iff$ A has a right inverse

Comment: A can be multiplied by any vector (0 x) to give null... That implies it isn't injective, correct?

Comment: $A$ is $2$x$1$ and hence maps a one dimensional space to a two dimensional space, so you're checking $Ax = 0 \implies x=0$ where $x$ is a scalar

Comment: oh.okay.that makes sense.So....,then why is my proof wrong?

Comment: You can check in the counterexample that $N(A) \cup N(B-C) \ne$ the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in a ring $R$, the cancellation law ''$ab=ac$ implies $b=c$'' holds more generally if $a$ is not a zero divisor, since $ab=ac$ gives $a(b-c)=0$ by distributivity. If $a$ is not a zero divisor, then $b-c=0$, i.e., $b=c$. So there is no need for $a$ to be a unit.

Comment: You used distributive property, so the ring doesn't actually have to be commutative, right?

Comment: However every matrix with entries from a field is either a unit or a zero divisor.

Comment: The same holds for residue class rings $Z_n$.

Answer (score 0):

***AB=AC***

***AB-AC=O***

***A(B-C)=O***

Similarly,

***BA=CA***

***BA-CA=O***

***(B-C)A=O***

So, in both cases, either

- ***A=O***,
- ***B=C***
- Rest of the cases where ***N(A)*** union ***N(B-C)***=all of space

By imposing the condition that ***N(A)={0}***, we ensure that the first doesn't happen, and when the third does,it implies ***B=C***

Thus, ***A*** being one to one necessarily implies ***B=C.***

Comment: Could someone please verify the validity of the claim...